# Interchange of rows to column in sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

how to interchange  rows to column,
i have a output like

```
 employeeName   payHead  amount

Samam          Basic    20000.000000 
Samam          Test1    11.000000
Samam          Test2    22.000000   
Ravi kumar     Test1    55.000000
Ravi kumar     Test2    66.000000
Ravi kumar     Basic    3000.000000
```

i need a output like

```
employeeName   Basic             Test1         Test2   

 Samam          20000.000000      11.000000    22.000000 
 Ravi kumar     3000.000000       55.000000    66.000000
```

Comment: You've tagged question with **PIVOT** so where is problem?

Comment: give me pivot syntax for that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795227/how-to-use-pivot-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

Simple [`PIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) query:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (employeeName  nvarchar(max),
                     payHead nvarchar(max),
                     amount float);

INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
('Samam',          'Basic',    20000.000000),
('Samam',          'Test1',    11.000000),
('Samam',          'Test2',    22.000000),   
('Ravi kumar',     'Test1',    55.000000),
('Ravi kumar',     'Test2',    66.000000),
('Ravi kumar',     'Basic',    3000.000000);

SELECT *
FROM @Test t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(amount)
    FOR payHead IN (Basic,Test1,Test2)
) as p
ORDER BY Basic;
```